# Select Rows in a Table in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Is there a way to select rows in table in SSRS? What I mean is, when a table is populated with rows of data, I would like to select the rows of a table and perform some action on them. Like in a grid view control, the user can select specific set of rows. Can we insert a checkbox control in SSRS table that can be used to select rows of a table and perform action on selected rows?

Comment: In SSRS ? I think the easiest way for such thing is export to Excel and manipulate it from there. Unless you are asking to hide rows/ columns based on values in which case you can do that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, what I am looking for is to select the rows of the table when I view the report online i.e., in report viewer control and perform certain action on selected rows like we do in Grid view control or in Excel Sheet.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are looking for is not available from SSRS out of the box. There are some hacks that you can use but they seem to be a lot more work than it's worth.

The basic idea is that a query in SSRS can include an Update or Insert command. Then you use parameters to track whether or not to run the update part and to capture your Primary Key or other field for your update. You would need to use the Action to act as the on-click event and it would only work for one row at a time.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1472163-391-1.aspx

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24009/